# Importing Django module from a subfolder

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project where in the project's root folder (where `manage.py` is) I can do

```
(venv) MyName-MacBook:mydjangoproject myname$ python
>>> import django
>>> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
>>>
```

However, when I create a subfolder, this doesn't work anymore

```
(venv) MyName-MacBook:mydjangoproject myname$ mkdir email && cd email
(venv) MyName-MacBook:email myname$ python
>>> import django
>>> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/MacBook:mydjangoproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core.mail.message import (
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/MacBook:mydjangoproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 7, in <module>
    from email import (
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/MacBook:mydjangoproject/email/email.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
ImportError: cannot import name 'EmailMessage'
>>>
```

I realise this is a very basic question, but I am a bit stuck. It's strange that I can import `django`, but not the other functions.

Comment: Can you include the full traceback from your exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your traceback I see you have a module named `email`.

Django tries to import from the builtin module `email` and the python interpreter thinks your module is the one to import. Try renaming that module to avoid name collisions and you should be fine

Edit: After your edit the problem becomes very clear. The python interpreter looks at your working directory before the builtins, finds an `email.py` and tries to import from that

Comment: I can't give you the details about why your module is being imported instead of the builtin one without more context

Answer (score 1):

You have a package named django in your project, don't you :) Don't do that- it will make you import the wrong thing by accident.